# FirebaseFunctions -swift h not found

Tags: xcode, google-cloud-functions, expo, cocoapods

I use expo to program an iOS app. When I run npx expo prebuild and try to run it in Xcode I get this error: FirebaseFunctions -swift h not found. Why is that? I successfully install it with pod install and can now see it in podfile.lock: - Firebase/CoreOnly (10.15.0):
- FirebaseCore (= 10.15.0)

- Firebase/DynamicLinks (10.15.0):

  - Firebase/CoreOnly
  - FirebaseDynamicLinks (~> 10.15.0)
- Firebase/Functions (10.15.0):

  - Firebase/CoreOnly
  - FirebaseFunctions (~> 10.15.0)
- FirebaseAppCheckInterop (10.16.0)
- FirebaseAuthInterop (10.16.0)
- FirebaseCore (10.15.0):

  - FirebaseCoreInternal (~> 10.0)
  - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.8)
  - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 7.8)
- FirebaseCoreExtension (10.16.0):

  - FirebaseCore (~> 10.0)
- FirebaseCoreInternal (10.16.0):

  - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.8)"
- FirebaseDynamicLinks (10.15.0):

  - FirebaseCore (~> 10.0)
- FirebaseFunctions (10.15.0):

  - FirebaseAppCheckInterop (~> 10.10)
  - FirebaseAuthInterop (~> 10.0)
  - FirebaseCore (~> 10.0)
  - FirebaseCoreExtension (~> 10.0)
  - FirebaseMessagingInterop (~> 10.0)
  - FirebaseSharedSwift (~> 10.0)
  - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (< 4.0, >= 2.1)
- FirebaseMessagingInterop (10.16.0)
- FirebaseSharedSwift (10.16.0)

Working app on Xcode